# How can I find the integral orthogonal group of a given symmetric positive definite form?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, singularity-theory

I wonder how one can study the integral orthogonal group of a given (symmetric, positive definite) bilinear form like the one described by the following matrix:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1       & -1  \\
 -1       & x_2 & -1 \\
 & -1 &\ddots\\
 \\
  & & & & x_{n-1} &-1 \\
    & & & & -1 &x_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am interested in this specific case where all the $x_i$'s are natural numbers $\geq 2$, with at least one of them being $\neq 2$. The problem of finding a matrix $A$ with integer coefficients such that $$A^TMA=M$$
originates from the study of hypersurface singulraity $f:(\mathbb{C}^3,0)\to (\mathbb{C},0)$ and its Milnor fiber. In particular, one of the restrictions that I can impose further is that the characateristic polynomial of $A$ should be a product of cyclotomic polynomials.

Any suggestion, reference or idea would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This answers the question:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2118555?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents